# Apache Flink streaming in cluster does not split jobs with workers

Tags: streaming, cluster-computing, apache-kafka, apache-flink

My objective is to setup a high throughput cluster using Kafka as source & Flink as the stream processing engine. Here's what I have done.

I have setup a 2-node cluster the following configuration on the master and the workers.

**Master flink-conf.yaml**

```
jobmanager.rpc.address: <MASTER_IP_ADDR> #localhost

jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123

jobmanager.heap.mb: 256

taskmanager.heap.mb: 512

taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 50

parallelism.default: 100
```

**Worker flink-conf.yaml**

```
jobmanager.rpc.address: <MASTER_IP_ADDR> #localhost

jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123

jobmanager.heap.mb: 512 #256

taskmanager.heap.mb: 1024 #512

taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 50

parallelism.default: 100
```

The `slaves` file on the Master node looks like this:

```
<WORKER_IP_ADDR>
localhost
```

The flink setup on both nodes is in a folder which has the same name. I start up the cluster on the master by running

```
bin/start-cluster-streaming.sh
```

This starts up the task manager on the Worker node.

My input source is Kafka. Here is the snippet.

```java
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
    StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

DataStreamSource<String> stream = 
    env.addSource(
    new KafkaSource<String>(kafkaUrl,kafkaTopic, new SimpleStringSchema()));
stream.addSink(stringSinkFunction);

env.execute("Kafka stream");
```

Here is my Sink function

```java
public class MySink implements SinkFunction<String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void invoke(String arg0) throws Exception {
        processMessage(arg0);
        System.out.println("Processed Message");
    }
}
```

Here are the Flink Dependencies in my pom.xml.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I run the packaged jar with this command on the master

```
bin/flink run flink-test-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

However when I insert messages into the Kafka topic I am able to account for all messages coming in from my Kafka topic (via debug messages in the invoke method of my `SinkFunction` implementation) on the Master node alone.

In the Job manager UI I am able to see 2 Task managers as below:
[image: Job Manager dashboard - task managers]

Also The dashboard looks like so :
[image]
**Questions:**

1. Why are the worker nodes not getting the tasks?
2. Am I missing some configuration?

Comment: Thank you for posting such a well-written question!
How do you get these debug messages on the master? Its not really possible to execute user code on the master (JobManager)
Are you using Flink 0.9.0 or 0.10-SNAPSHOT?
How does your `stringSinkFunction` look like? (Is it just printing to standard out?)

Comment: @rmetzger, You're welcome. I have updated the question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you. 
When the job is running, can you check the Flink web interface running on port 8081 to see if the job is running properly (and on the slave as well).
Are you starting one taskManager or two?

Comment: I've checked the web interface and found no problems. As such since I can see all messages printed in the sink function I believe the job executes properly. I run the `start-cluster-streaming.sh` on the master node which seems to start a task manager on the slave node. So essentially there are 2 task managers(one on each node).

Comment: The number of started TM depends on the master-node-local file "conf/slaves". Did you configure a TM for both nodes there? Per default, only "localhost" is configured there, ie, a single TM on the same machine as JobManager is running (ie, your master)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax  Yes. The slaves file on the master node has the slave node IP address as the first line. I believe without this the task-manager on the slave would not get autostarted when I run start-cluster-streaming.sh on the master.

Comment: Ok. Great! Does the slave file contains "localhost", too? In JobManager UI, you see two TMs? Is the sink chained to the source? You can check in JobManager UI when clicking on the running job.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Updated the question with the responses. In general I believe my reply is "Yes" to all of your questions.

Comment: @SudarshanShubakar, from the screenshots it looks that you've 2 TMs registered with 50 slots each. This also corresponds with your configuration. Moreover, it looks as if your job is executed properly. In each of the 100 slots there is the task `Custom Source -> Stream Sink (x/100)` deployed. Therefore, I'm wondering what's not working for you. Can it be that your topic has less than `100` partitions? Since Flink creates a mapping between Kafka partition and source task, there would be tasks which don't receive any input.

Comment: ok@TillRohrmann This may be the issue. I believe there are less than 100 partitiions on the Kafka topic. Let me report back after changing this.

Comment: Because you source and sink is chained, data in keeps local where it is ingested into the system. If you want to distribute data you need to break the chaining, by applying "rebalance()", ie,  stream.rebalance().addSink(stringSinkFunction); (from your example)

Comment: Alright @TillRohrmann comment solved the problem. Can you convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for your suggestion. I will read up more on this and possibly use it.

Comment: @SudarshanShubakar, I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When reading from a Kafka source in Flink, the maximum degree of parallelism for the source task is limited by the number of partitions of a given Kafka topic. A Kafka partition is the smallest unit which can be consumed by a source task in Flink. If there are more partitions than source tasks, then some tasks will consume multiple partitions.

Consequently, in order to supply input to all of your 100 tasks, you should assure that your Kafka topic has at least 100 partitions.

If you cannot change the number of partitions of your topic, then it is also possible to initially read from Kafka using a lower degree of parallelism using the `setParallelism` method. Alternatively, you can use the `rebalance` method which will shuffle your data across all available tasks of the preceding operation.

Comment: Accepted this answer as it solved my problem.  However I would like to understand further what you've mentioned in the last part of your answer. What exactly do you mean when you say "initially read from Kafka using a lower degree of parallelism using the setParallelism method"? How would I reset it once set?  Also I would have to try out rebalance, just adding it into the code did not seem to work for me for this problem.

Comment: You can set the parallelism on an operator basis (e.g. map, filter, reduce function). The operators will then be executed with the given parallelism. The `setParallelism` method overrides the default parallelism or the parallelism which you specify at the `ExecutionEnvironment`.